Can’t parse input data: ‘tz^xt8<^_^y1’ in sqoop export
I am trying to execute a sqoop export from hive to oracle
Command:
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb \
--username myuser \
--password mypass \
--table mytable \
--export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/mytable \
--input-null-string '\\N' \
--input-null-non-string '\\N' \ —Ctrl-chars

Still no luck, I am facing can’t parse input data
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb \
--username myuser \
--password mypass \
--table mytable \
--export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/mytable \
--input-null-string '\x00' \
--input-null-non-string '\x00' \
--input-filter "sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g'”

